# How to only register clicks on an image [Pygame]

Tags: python, pygame

I am really new to programming and making games in pygame. I have been having a blast trying to make my own simple games but recently I got stuck and I don't know how to program this.

I am making a 2D Mining game. My cursor is a pick and I have an image of a rock blitted in the center of my screen. How do I make that only when I click on the rock it will react (pick will have an animation, sound will play and will gain 1 rock in "inventory"

I made the rock and gave it a transparent background...every part of the visible rock must be clickable.

(Right now I can click anywhere on the screen and it will add one rock to my inventory, obviously I dont want this.)

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Miner Click")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960,600))
width = 960
height = 600

GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BROWN = (84,27,1) 
GREY = (198,198,198)

greenbg = pygame.image.load("greenbg.jpg").convert()
rockbutton = pygame.image.load("rockbutton.png").convert_alpha()
woodbutton = pygame.image.load("woodbutton.png").convert_alpha()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
pick = pygame.image.load("pick.png").convert_alpha()
axe = pygame.image.load("axesmall.png").convert_alpha()
rock = pygame.image.load("rock.png").convert_alpha()

clicks = 0
wood = 0

stonefont = pygame.font.SysFont("verdana", 29, True)
woodfont = pygame.font.SysFont("verdana", 29, True)
clicktext = stonefont.render('Rock: ' +str(clicks), 2, (GREY))
woodtext = woodfont.render('Wood: ' +str(wood), 2, (BROWN))
boxsize = clicktext.get_rect()
RocksX = 125
WoodX = 113

class Rock:
def __init__(self, rock):
    self.rock = rock

coordfont = pygame.font.SysFont("verdana", 12, True)



while True:
clock.tick(60)
screen.fill((255,255,255))
screen.blit(greenbg, (0,0))
screen.blit(rock, (250,210))
x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
coords = x,y
label = coordfont.render("Coordinates: "+str(coords), 1, (GREY))
screen.blit(label, (790, 10))
screen.blit(rockbutton, (25,25))
screen.blit(woodbutton, (25,100))
clicktext = stonefont.render(' ' +str(clicks), 2, (GREY))
woodtext = woodfont.render(' ' +str(wood), 2, (BROWN))
screen.blit(clicktext, [RocksX,38])
screen.blit(woodtext, [139,WoodX])
screen.blit(pick, (x-75,y-50))
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE: 
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        clicks+=1
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
        wood+=1


    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that the variable clicks is used in stonefont like so:

```
stonefont.render(' ' +str(clicks), 2, (GREY)
```

I am going to assume that is a reference to the amount of rocks in the inventory. But I noticed that in your MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event it will add a stone whenever the mouse is clicked, so to fix this I would check to see if the mouse was over the rock when clicked like so, (replacing your current MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event.)

```
   elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if x>125 and x<(entertherockswidthhere) and y>38 and y<(entertherocksheighthere):
             clicks+=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have made it alot better. But my image is not perfectly square, so there are areas with transparency. This means that you can click and even though your not clicking on the rock it will still add 1 rock to your inventory.   So that means it would take alot more then 4 coordinates to define exactly where each part of the rock begins and ends as it is a complex polygon shape. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Well, that would be pretty difficult. Just make sure you crop the image, and possibly set the collision box a couple pixels smaller than it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the bounds of the mouse cooardinates when clicked under the mouse click event handler like this ..

```
if x > rock.x and x < rock.x + rock.width:
    clicks += 1 # or whatever you want to happen here ..
```